# PHP connection to the database to check user login information

Tags: php

I wrote this code but it's not working. It's basically not doing anything. This form is placed on the login.php where the form is. The form action is set to php self so it sends the info to itself and I am trying to check if the information is valid or not with this code;

```
if ($_POST['username'] != "" && $_POST['password'] != "") {
$data = mysqli_query($dbcon, "  SELECT * 
                                FROM  `users` 
                                WHERE  `user_name` LIKE  '".$_POST['username']."'
                                AND  `user_password` LIKE  '".$_POST['password']."'") or die(mysql_error());

        // if this user exists
        if ($data->num_rows == 1) {
                $result_row = $data->fetch_object();
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                $_SESSION['user_password'] = $result_row->user_password;
                $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = 1;
        } else {
            "Wrong Password";
        }

}
```

Comment: Do you get error or what happens?

Comment: You should be calling `mysqli_error($dbcon)`, not `mysql_error()`. You can't mix mysql_XXX and mysqli_XXX function.

Comment: no error. nothing happens.. it just looks like reloads

Comment: You didn't forget to put `session_start();` somewhere? Also, you can use `WHERE user_name = '...'` instead of like. And please, sanitize your inputs!

Comment: and you forget `echo` in `"Wrong Passowrd"`

Comment: good catch I'll fixed that. but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: If the query is successful, it doesn't display anything, so the page will just reload.

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` with the password. If the password contains wildcard characters `%` or `_` it won't do the right thing.

Comment: all fixed with your corrections guys. Appreciated. I hate to miss small stuff like this.. Thanks!! :)

Comment: what should I use as a sql in this case for safest?

Comment: I changed it to =.. I hope thats a good idea.

Comment: @user627850 you should not store plain text passwords.

Comment: its correct. I will add password encryption too. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

with other people's help problem solved!

Thanks everyone!

```
if ($_POST['username'] != "" && $_POST['password'] != "") {
$data = mysqli_query($dbcon, "  SELECT * 
                                FROM  `users` 
                                WHERE  `user_name` =  '".$_POST['username']."'
                                AND  `user_password` =  '".$_POST['password']."'") or die(mysqli_error());

        // if this user exists
        if ($data->num_rows == 1) {
                session_start();
                $result_row = $data->fetch_object();
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                $_SESSION['user_password'] = $result_row->user_password;
                $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = 1;
        } else {
            echo "Wrong Password";
        }

}
```

Comment: Use prepared statements and don't repeat your errors such as allowing SQL Injection.

Comment: @Prix: He *is* the OP.

Comment: I am just remembering php .. so I have forgotten most of the stuff. I know I have to add sql injection and other security stuff.. I just need to catch up..